# why hash join only usable with equal join?

Tags: mysql, hash, hashtable

i have to develop hash join in storage engine structure. thus, i want to know why hash join only useful with equal join in MySQL.

i has read MySQL document here, https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/hash-join-in-mysql-8/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hash-joins.html. i expected the exactly structure about that. hash table, hash join in MySQL.

Comment: In normal database systems, it's not possible to provide a *general purpose* order preserving hash function, so it's not possible for the hash join to support any comparison other than equality.

Comment: it is not normal database system. because, i use additional hardware device CSD which means Computational Storage Drive. CSD supports SSD's computing. i use MySQL for query engine. but, i have to develop storage engine like RocksDB. so, i have to implement full scan and index scan. my question related to index scan. hash join is useful in index scan.